# How to parse nested keys and values using JsonReader?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am learning Java and I'm trying to make a Fortnite stat tracking app. I'm using the Fortnite tracker API and `JsonReader` to read the keys and values that get returned. This works fine but the problem is the stats like 'kills' etc are nested and I'm not sure how to read those.

Can I read nested keys and values using `JsonReader`?
I tried `JSONObject` but I'm not entirely sure I was using it correctly so I didn't get very far.

```
{   "accountId": "c48bb072-f321-4572-9069-1c551d074949",   "platformId": 1,   "platformName": "xbox",   "platformNameLong": "Xbox",   "epicUserHandle": "playername",   "stats": {
    "p2": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1,
        "value": "1",
        "rank": 852977,
        "percentile": 100.0,
        "displayValue": "1"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 236074,
        "value": "236074",
        "rank": 6535595,
        "percentile": 3.0,
        "displayValue": "236,074"
      }
```

Above is a sample of the information that I pulled so that you can see the structure

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    Button submit;
    EditText tbplatform;
    EditText tbhandle;
    String TAG = "TESTRUN";
    String id = "";

    InputStreamReader responseBodyReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOne);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTwo);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvThree);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        tbplatform = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbPlatform);
        tbhandle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbHandle);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String platform = String.valueOf(tbplatform.getText());
                final String username = String.valueOf(tbhandle.getText());

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // All your networking logic
                // should be here

                // Create URL
                URL githubEndpoint = null;
                try {
                    githubEndpoint = new URL("https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/" + platform+ "/" + username);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create connection
                HttpsURLConnection myConnection = null;
                try {
                    myConnection =
                            (HttpsURLConnection) githubEndpoint.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                myConnection.setRequestProperty("TRN-Api-Key", "API_KEY_HERE");

                try {
                    if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();
                        responseBodyReader =
                                new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");


                        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(responseBodyReader);


                        jsonReader.beginObject(); // Start processing the JSON object

                        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { // Loop through all keys
                            final String key = jsonReader.nextName(); // Fetch the next key

                            //Log.v(TAG, key);

                            if (key.equals("epicUserHandle") || key.equals("platformName") || key.equals("accountId")) { // Check if desired key
                                // Fetch the value as a String
                                final String value = jsonReader.nextString();

                                if (key.equals("epicUserHandle")) {
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Gamertag: " + value);


                                }
                                if (key.equals("platformName")) {
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Console: " + value);
                                }
                                if (key.equals("stats")) {

                                    Log.v(TAG, "Kills: " + value);
                                }

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        //stuff that updates ui
                                        if(key.equals("epicUserHandle")) {
                                            tv.setText("Username: " + value);
                                        }
                                        if(key.equals("platformName")) {
                                            tv2.setText("Platform: " +value);
                                        }
                                        if(key.equals("accountId")) {
                                            tv3.setText("Account ID: " +value);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                //Log.v(TAG, "" +value);

                                // Do something with the value
                                // ...

                                //break; // Break out of the loop
                            } else {
                                jsonReader.skipValue(); // Skip values of other keys
                            }

                        }

                        jsonReader.close();

                        myConnection.disconnect();
                    } else {
                        // Error handling code goes here
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
     }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using google gson is better option. Its easy to use.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, I've been trying to use GSON. I've set up classes and the getters and setters but I've never used this before so I'm having issues actually getting the info from the httprequest to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this may help you**

> You Need To Create Some Classes As Given Below

```
class Score implements Serializable {
private String label;
private String field;
private String category;
private Integer valueInt;
private String value;
private Integer rank;
private Double percentile;
private String displayValue;

public Score() {
    this("", "", "", 0, "", 0, 0.0, "");
}

public Score(String label, String field,
             String category, Integer valueInt,
             String value, Integer rank,
             Double percentile, String displayValue) {
    this.label = label;
    this.field = field;
    this.category = category;
    this.valueInt = valueInt;
    this.value = value;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.percentile = percentile;
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Integer getValueInt() {
    return valueInt;
}

public void setValueInt(Integer valueInt) {
    this.valueInt = valueInt;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(Integer rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public Double getPercentile() {
    return percentile;
}

public void setPercentile(Double percentile) {
    this.percentile = percentile;
}

public String getDisplayValue() {
    return displayValue;
}

public void setDisplayValue(String displayValue) {
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}
}

class TRNRating implements Serializable {

private String label;
private String field;
private String category;
private Integer valueInt;
private String value;
private Integer rank;
private Double percentile;
private String displayValue;

public TRNRating() {
    this("", "", "", 0, "", 0, 0.0, "");
}

public TRNRating(String label, String field,
                 String category, Integer valueInt,
                 String value, Integer rank,
                 Double percentile, String displayValue) {
    this.label = label;
    this.field = field;
    this.category = category;
    this.valueInt = valueInt;
    this.value = value;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.percentile = percentile;
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Integer getValueInt() {
    return valueInt;
}

public void setValueInt(Integer valueInt) {
    this.valueInt = valueInt;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(Integer rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public Double getPercentile() {
    return percentile;
}

public void setPercentile(Double percentile) {
    this.percentile = percentile;
}

public String getDisplayValue() {
    return displayValue;
}

public void setDisplayValue(String displayValue) {
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}
}

class P2 implements Serializable {
private TRNRating trnRating;
private Score score;

public P2() {
    this(new TRNRating(), new Score());
}

public P2(TRNRating trnRating, Score score) {
    this.trnRating = trnRating;
    this.score = score;
}

public TRNRating getTrnRating() {
    return trnRating;
}

public void setTrnRating(TRNRating trnRating) {
    this.trnRating = trnRating;
}

public Score getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(Score score) {
    this.score = score;
}
}

class Stats implements Serializable {
private P2 p2;

public Stats() {
    this(new P2());
}

public Stats(P2 p2) {
    this.p2 = p2;
}
}

//You Need To Change Name Of This Class
class Response implements Serializable {
private String accountId;
private Integer platformId;
private String platformName;
private String platformNameLong;
private String epicUserHandle;
private Stats stats;

public Response() {
    this("", 0, "", "", "", new Stats());
}

public Response(String accountId, Integer platformId,
                String platformName, String platformNameLong,
                String epicUserHandle, Stats stats) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.platformId = platformId;
    this.platformName = platformName;
    this.platformNameLong = platformNameLong;
    this.epicUserHandle = epicUserHandle;
    this.stats = stats;
}

public String getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
}

public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

public Integer getPlatformId() {
    return platformId;
}

public void setPlatformId(Integer platformId) {
    this.platformId = platformId;
}

public String getPlatformName() {
    return platformName;
}

public void setPlatformName(String platformName) {
    this.platformName = platformName;
}

public String getPlatformNameLong() {
    return platformNameLong;
}

public void setPlatformNameLong(String platformNameLong) {
    this.platformNameLong = platformNameLong;
}

public String getEpicUserHandle() {
    return epicUserHandle;
}

public void setEpicUserHandle(String epicUserHandle) {
    this.epicUserHandle = epicUserHandle;
}

public Stats getStats() {
    return stats;
}

public void setStats(Stats stats) {
    this.stats = stats;
}
}
```

> If your response is same as explained in question. Then this will work.

```
//In your code after status check you need to do like this
if (myConnection.getResopnseCode() == 200) {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(responseBodyReader);
    String read = null, entireResponse = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(read);
    }
    entireResponse = sb.toString();

    //You need to change name of response class
    Response response = new Gson().fromJson(entireResponse , Response.class);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this out now. I am just a little confused however at what the `responseString` is in the line: `Response response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, Response.class);`

Comment: @Brandan I made change. It should be entireResponse.